# Drag and drop from jsTree to input form field

Tags: jquery, html, forms, filesystems, jstree

I have a jsTree of a filesystem, folders and files, and I would like to drag a file node from the tree and drop it into an `input` field, inserting the full pathname into the form field.

Currently, when I attempt to drag any node from the tree into the form field, I get back the URL of the web page, along with a hash mark, e.g. `https://example.com/#`. If I change the link href of the node's data, the hash changes to the new href, but I still get the protocol and host (`https://example.com/newHref`).

Assuming the modification I described is possible, how would I configure the jsTree and form to accomplish this?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using a JSON data source, when adding an `href` attribute to the `data` list's `attr` list, it seems helpful to use the `file://` protocol, e.g.:

```
{
  "data" : {
     "icon" : "/js/_demo/folder.png",
     "title" : "workspace",
     "attr" : {
        "href" : "file:///home/areynolds/workspace"
     }
  },
  "attr" : {
     "rel" : "folder",
     "id" : "/home/areynolds/workspace"
  },
  "state" : "closed"
}
```

The node's link can then be dragged and dropped into an HTML `input` field.

One could either use the `file://` href as-is, or use a bit of JavaScript or jQuery to clean up the path.

If using an HTML data source, using `file://` in the anchor's `href` accomplishes the same result.